# API to classify location as urban, suburban, or rural

Tags: api, web

I'm trying to classify colleges as having a urban/suburban/rural location. I can't seem to find any websites that classify colleges in these categories (odd, right?). So I was thinking of using the location of the school to classify the college as urban/suburban/rural. Are there any apis or even websites (where I would have to use web scraping) that could classify a location as urban/suburban/rural?

Comment: I am doing something similar, classifying residential blocks in the UK as either rural or urban. I was looking for an API or algoithm to do this too, but didn't find one. 

Now my chosen method (which I have not implemented yet) is to download the classifications from the office for national statistics with a geocode. Then I am going to join the table of geocoded residential locations with the urban/rural classifications on geocode. This should enable me to categorise each residential block.